# What is the difference between integrals and contour integrals?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I understand integrals but what are contour integrals?

Comment: and if someone could show a simple example explaining, would be appriciated

Comment: [Wikipedia Contour Integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration) is a perfect place to look.

Answer (score 3):

Integrals, as you call them, and contour integrals are the same thing at a basic level: they are limits of certain sums over functions.  The practical difference, however, is that the contour integral really represents one way, out of infinitely many, to integrate a function between 2 points, Point A and Point B, in a plane.  The integral, on the other hand, has only one path by which to integrate from Point A to Point B.

Further, it makes sense to speak of closed contour integrals - well, OK, you could speak of integrating a function from Point A to Point B, and back again on the real line, but that isn't very interesting.  On the other hand, you can speak of going from Point A to Point B along one path, and then from Point B back to Point A along a different path.  In some cases, the net result is not zero.  (In fact, it only is when the function in question is analytic on and within the contours.)